# How to scale and shift a signal with a single opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I tried to scale the signal by 3 times with Av=1+R2/R1. but how do I shift it up by 1v?
for example: a 0.2/2V VIN into 0.6/6V and shift it up by 1v to 1.6/7v?
I managed to scale it but I don't know how to shift the Vout signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vin+ controls offset.
Vin- controls offset and gain.

If you split Rin=R1 into two resistors such that Thevenin Req is the same value but Veq = Voutput offset/Av then you achieve this with one Op Amp.

Do for Av-=-2 you need a Vin- offset of -0.5V or you could do the same with Vin+ .

Attenuate with pullup to attenuate and add offset so get overall ( 1+|Av-|) Vin * R3/(R3+R4) = 3Vin+1V.

That assumes you can use Vcc to get an accurate offset then amplify that + input signal to get [desired transfer function.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCMIDMZJ0QNgBwc5rcBOddEAVkzLIlIFMBaOOAKAEMQAmUkudCHEHhApxSIBqLixYURHHYAWAlNkECmNTLkSpYJgHckWAb0MUi4faeN8j7BRYBOHLiHP9zERrCZPOJc3Dy8q4k1N5OgcF2US7R4AKk3gZ%20AgDsJClxugDmAkEhecFyFBC6yS7mKZEW5Rn2mansjs4ZjS1IpE2eSe2InUhgwX1dTLmETfzjIPIw8WXt7G3IUW26AB4CmKkg6NvscNupEFHBAErMG8gQu0jIIEfTHGfsTBtwmKKcBBwiHOhNJxAp0Qrw4Gi%20SHYFHY-0e9lO8lBiEwRXU03Y3ymgIANgB7FgAEyYBya1TijCaClK90oompKFEADVcdiAC4sbI0JinAQECYYQq3UICaazBlzKCkJgAB16-RSyKKj10suWHCWgwGStKMqscXkiEp9gQwRVVkE03QRRMCB1AGU5aS%20R0uvEAGYsbEAZxo8ReuNcO1NooIe0gdOgMEQSn%20dI4gZBQA)

[image]

Tap the switch, observe Vpp gain of 3

Comment: This is the simplest way. Any questions? The switch is just for proof .

Comment: thank you, I got it. And thanks again for that website that was a lot of help

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a negative voltage available? If so, shift R1 input by -0.5V. This will translate to the output as:

- Vout = (inverting input * -R2/R1) + (non-inverting input * (1 + R2/R1) )

Example:

[image]

More generally, if you treat your amplifier as a *differential* you have options to inject voltage on the (+) or (-) side to achieve the offset you want.

More about differential amplifiers here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html

This version works on the (+) side so doesn't need any negative voltage.
[image]

Notice the inverting gain is adjusted to be 5, for a total non-inverting gain of 6. This is because the input is attenuated by 50% (Why? Look into how a *voltage summer* works), so we have a net non-inverting gain of 3.

Finally, 0.3333V (1/3 of 1V) is a weird voltage. You can work out a Thevenin equivalent for it using a voltage divider and achieve the same thing (that is, 1/3V in series with 1k.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a second op-amp, a negative voltage reference or require the input impedance to be low and capable of sinking some current.